# Using Google Calendar API on my website

Tags: php, html, api, google-calendar-api

I'm currently using the iframe embed Google Calendars offers you for my website, shown here --> http://www.radiovalerie.org/schedule

I want to try and figure out how to use the Calendar API to grab all the information from it, and format it into my own custom style, and use it on the front page just to show which event is currently now on, or, which events are coming up that day (this is for a radio station).

I'm not an incredibly advanced coder (as you'll be able to see, the code for my website is pretty horrible), so I'm unsure as to where to begin looking in the Calendar API docs for how to utilise it in my website. I've never used anything with API's before.

Would somebody here be able to point me to an easy example of how to do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Examples get easier after some research, so dive into those calendar Api docs (and some serious browser search) and you will eventually happily understand how it works.

You can check w3 usage examples:
http://www.w3.org/TR/calendar-api/#usage-example

and Google code samples: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/samples.html (check the javascript ones)

And you can ask here if you have any particular questions **once** you are trying the Api :)

Comment: Can you embed Google Calendar onto your website and be able to edit it?

Comment: @Yoda The calendar API I linked is no longer supported, I think. You should probably look for a newer plugin, or investigate the new calendar API. Back in 2011 it was editable, I'm not sure about now...